# Find Minor axis points

Tags: math

I have two points of major axis of ellipse and I have length of minor axis.I Want to find the minor axis points.
One approach I thought of was by finding slope of major axis.then find the slope of minor axis.and we have center point so we get one equation.Other equation can be obtained using distance formula..but this makes it quadratic . Is some linear solution possible?

Comment: What are you talking about? Ellipse?

Comment: Yes I am talking about ellipse

Comment: what points is known (endpoints of major axis or any arbitrary?) what else you do know? do you need absolute or relative solution? adding image would be a good idea (post it somewhere add link and someone will copy it here) Is this arbitrary or axis aligned ellipse ? ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematics and should be moved to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @spektre the end points of major axis and the length of minor axis.
I am coding that so i m asking for a solution here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rotations by 90° to formulate this. Suppose your major axis endpoints are (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>). Furthrmore, suppose that sqrt((x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)=a is the length of the major axis and b is the minor axis length. Then M=½(x<sub>1</sub>+x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>+y<sub>2</sub>) is the center of the ellipse, and v=½(x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>) is a vector from that center to one of the major axis endpoints. Therefore w=b/(2a)*(y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>) is a vector from the midpoint to one endpoint of the minor axis, and -w is the other. So M±w are the two endpoints.

Comment: sadly stackoverflow doesn't support math syntax like many other stackexchange sites :( the admins told me a while ago that it's due to the server overhead and SO's volume compared to the other sites.

Comment: @Adam. I know :( I can't understand it, since MathJax is mostly CLient-Side, particularly if used with a CDN. But the problem here was that I'm very active on Math SE as well, and actually missed the fact that this question was *not* asked on Math SE.

Answer (score 2):

**So I see it like this:**

- [image]
- blue things are known
- red are unknown and wanted
- `A0,A1` - major axis endpoints
- `a` - major axis length
- `B0,B1` - minor axis endpoints
- `b` - minor axis length
- `C` - ellipse center

So with some vector math is that easy:

```
// midpoint is just average of endpoints ...
C=(A0+A1)/2

// major axis size
a=|A1-A0|

// now we need vector `b0` perpendicular to major axis
// in 3D use cross product but for that you need at leas to know 1 more point not on major axis
// in 2D simply swap x,y coordinates and make one negated (that is rotation by 90 degrees) so:
b0.x=(A1.y-A0.y)
b0.y=(A0.x-A1.x)
// now make the b0 vector length equal to halve of minor axis length
b0=0.5*b0*b/|b0|
// hope you know how to compute absolute value of 2D vector (|v|=`sqrt(v.x*v.x+v.y*v.y)`)

// now the endpoints are easy
B0=C+b0
B1=C-b0
```

- if you have some inputs different like on image
- for example half axises instead of full then C point is already known
- and or b is already halve so no need for multiplication by 0.5
- but a needs to be multiplied by it instead to get also half size

Comment: @user3845376 this is almost the same as MvG's answer but I get the impression from your comment you have full axis endpoints/sizes instead of semi axises (half the size) ... if also slope is needed then use atanxy or atan2 on (A0-C) vector ...

Comment: Yes this is also very nice..Thank you..